# VBS script wont enter loop

Tags: html, vbscript

My script will not enter either of the For loops, I have been using MsgBox to help check and it seems that it just skips over the entire loop without entering it.
"<<<" indicates where issue starts

```
'==========================================================
 Sub Read
'======================================================

'Read Row 
RR  = 6
PC  = 25
```

at this point the script is supposed to enter a loop which cycles through documents and files to read and store data

```
MsgBox "front For"                           <<<

For Cx = 1 to Cint(vTFileC)
    MsgBox "in loop 1"
    Cxx = 1

    'Setting Target
    Target  = CStr(FullPath & "\" & vTFolder & "\"& vTFile & Cx &".html")

    For  x = Cxx to PC
        MsgBox "in loop 2"

        'Sets Book 1
        set oBook1 = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Target)

        'Reading Table
        set Stock   = oExcel.Cells(RR,5)
        set ID      = oExcel.Cells(RR,3)

        'Displays Info
        MsgBox ( Cx &"/"& vTFileC &" RR: "& RR & " ID: " & ID & " Stock: " & Stock )

        'Closes Book 1
        oBook1.Close

        MsgBox "3"
        call Find_Write_Row

        r   = r   + 1
        Cxx = Cxx + 1
        RR  = RR  + 1
    Next

    'to cycle to next document
    Cx = Cx + 1

Next
```

This is where the script continues, jumping everything between here and the last section of non-code.

```
MsgBox "End"

'Quitting
oExcel.Quit

End Sub
'==========================================================
```

This is causing my script to run and then instantly close without doing anything.

This is the section of my script which sets some of the values being used

```
'==========================================================
' HTML INPUTS
'======================================================
    'Sets Target folder from HTML input
    set oTFolder = document.getElementById("Folder_")
    vTFolder = oTFolder.value

    'Sets Target file from HTML input 
    set oTFile = document.getElementById("File_")
    vTFile = oTFile.value

    'Sets file count from HTML input
    set oTFileC = document.getElementById("C_")
    vTFileC = oTFileC.value

    'Toggles visibility of excel
    set oVT = document.getElementById("VT")
    vVT = oVT.value
'==========================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `For Cx = 1 to Cint(vTFileC)` does not enter the loop, then `Cint(vTFileC)` evaluates to something that is less than 1. So `vTFileC` needs to be examined:

```
>> MsgBox TypeName(vTFileC)
>> MsgBox vTFileC
>> MsgBox CInt(vTFileC)
```

Comment: comes back with
Empty
" "
0